# Polyhedra with minimal edge length

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra

Given a fixed volume and fixed surface area I would like to construct polyhedra that minimize the total length of the edges.  This seems like a straight-forward problem to solve by brute force for reasonably small number of vertices, but I imagine this has already been done, or at least considered.

Can anybody think of a source for such structures?

Comment: I think Ken Brakke's program surface evolver is well suited for this purpose. It's free and available at:
http://www.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/evolver.html

Answer (score 3):

This has been considered, see, for example, [this report.](http://cnx.org/content/m18831/latest/?collection=col10523/latest)

Comment: From Igor's link: [B01] S. Berger, Edge Length Minimizing Polyhedra, Thesis, Rice University, (2001)

Comment: Thanks for the citation, but the thesis looks at either fixed area or fixed volume.  A more concrete example of the question would be:  find a shape that encloses 1m^3 of volume, using 5m^2 of flat material, s.t. the total length of the seams is minimized.